# How to safely switch a target table with a staging table data in Synapse dedicated pool stored procedure?

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have an ADF copy activity that copies data into a Synapse dedicated sql pool table, I'm calling this my staging table. I'm trying to create a SP that would take the staging table and the target table and sort of switch them seamlessly so that business users aren't affected.

At this point I'm not sure what the best process to do this is for Synapse dedicated pool as I've encountered limitations regarding switching names.

This is the SP I currently have but I've encountered errors with using parameters and switching names every time I try to execute it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RenameStagingTableToDedicatedTable]
(
    @Schema VARCHAR(MAX),
    @StagingTableName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @DedicatedTableName VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Check if the Dedicated table exists
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U' AND name = @DedicatedTableName)
    BEGIN
        -- Rename the staging table to the Dedicated table
        RENAME OBJECT [@Schema].[@StagingTableName] TO [@DedicatedTableName]
 
        -- Drop the existing Dedicated table
        EXEC ('DROP TABLE ' + @DedicatedTableName)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- The Dedicated table does not exist, so rename the staging table to the Dedicated table
        RENAME OBJECT [@Schema].[@StagingTableName] TO [@DedicatedTableName]
 
    END
END
GO
```

Can anyone provide some guidance?

Comment: can you add what you tried and when you want to swap this table names?

Comment: You can't embed names using parameters like that, you need to use dynamic SQL with `EXEC`

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you want to rename table name. Try using `sp_rename` or build a sql statement fully as string and execute it.

Comment: sp_rename is limited in Synapse unfortunaly, so tables can't be renamed. I was able to resolve this by using RENAME OBJECT